# Need to check minimum 2 or more emails in one field in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Right now I have it like this

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  id="EmailAddresses" 
  required 
  name="EmailAddresses" 
  data-ng-pattern="/.+@.+/" 
  placeholder="yourname@organization.org; name@organization.org">

<div data-ng-message="pattern">
This needs to be a valid email or a semicolon separated list of emails </div>
```

which works fine if I have atleast 1 email in the field but I want to check if it has at least 2 emails separated by a semicolon in the same field.. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your current code? Also, I assume by 'email' you mean 'email address', correct?

Comment: You can modify built in email validator by providing the logic within your own directive https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#modifying-built-in-validators. You need to make such directive and then ask further if you need help about details.

Comment: You didn't specify where this validation is occurring so I'll assume it's in your controller. Split the string into an array using the semi-colon as the split character. If array.length == 1 then there's [potentially] a single email address so it fails your check for at least 2 email addresses. Then you can loop the array elements and apply your validation to each. If you are looking for a monster regex to do this in markup you'll have to poke around and cobble one together.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Modifying built-in validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#modifying-built-in-validators) you need to split the string from the input and invalidate the form if one of the substring is invalid. This is just a naive example to get you started:

#### Plunk

https://plnkr.co/edit/ABQg3zba7f9sPei4?p=preview

#### JS

```
var app = angular.module('customEmailValidation',[]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.email = '';
    $scope.submitForm = function(){
    }
}]);

app.directive('multimail', function() {
    var EMAIL_REGEXP = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/i;

    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            // only apply the validator if ngModel is present and AngularJS has added the email validator
            if (ctrl && ctrl.$validators.email) {

                // this will overwrite the default AngularJS email validator
                ctrl.$validators.email = function(modelValue) {
                    if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    var mails = [];
                    if (modelValue.indexOf(' ') > 0) {
                        mails = modelValue.split(' ');
                    } else {
                        mails.push(modelValue);
                    }
                    var valid = true;
                    for(var i = 0; i < mails.length; i++) {
                        if (!EMAIL_REGEXP.test(mails[i])) {
                            valid = false;
                        }
                    }
                    return valid;
                };
            }
        }
    };
});
```

#### HTML

```
<body ng-app="customEmailValidation" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <form name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">   
            <label>Email Address</label>
                <input
                    multimail
                    type="email"
                    id="EmailAddresses"
                    required
                    name="EmailAddresses"
                    ng-model="email"
                    name="email"
                    placeholder="yourname@organization.org name@organization.org">

                <div class="error" ng-show="!!myForm.email.$error">
                    <p ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">This is a required field</p>
                    <p ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Your email address is invalid</p>
                </div> 
                <button type="sumbit">Submit</button>     
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom directive which can split email address by semicolon, iterate through each & validate.

Comment: This is already said in the question comment section. Please provide more specific or different answer from the ones in the comment.